# How can I make my loop rendering list elements catch only the first time the list is created?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

It is important that this is done from the template, and not via JQuery DOM class modifications at in my Meteor functions (E.g. without doing this from `Template.list.rendered`)

I want to be able to do the following:

```html
<template name="list">
<div id="playlist_container">
  <ul id="playlist">
    {{#each my_playlist}}
    {{#each songs}}
        <li id="{{index}}" class="list_element">
               //# if list being rendered the first time
                    <div class="hide_song"></div>
               //else
                    <div class="next_song"></div>                 
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    {{/each}}   
  </ul>
</div>
</template>
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is definitely possible. There are probably a number of ways to do this. This is the one that came first to my mind (not tested):

```html
<template name="list">
<div id="playlist_container">
  <ul id="playlist">
    {{#each my_playlist}}
    {{#each songs}}
        <li id="{{index}}" class="list_element">
          {{#if renderedBefore}}
          <div class="next_song"></div>                 
          {{else}}
          <div class="hide_song"></div>
          {{/if}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    {{/each}}   
  </ul>
</div>
</template>
```

An in JS:

```js
Session.setDefault("renderedBefore", false);

Template.list.rendered = function() {
    Session.set("renderedBefore", true);
}

Template.list.renderedBefore = function() {
    return Session.get('renderedBefore');
}
```

Comment: Hello @ChristianF, I did consider a similar solution perviously. However, your answer relies on the .rendered function running everytime a list item is updated. However in the Template Preview 0 that I am using, the `rendered` callback only fires once - https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/New-Template-Engine-Preview

Any other workarounds?

Comment: maybe I misunderstood the question. Isn't that what you want? only on first render show the .hide_song div, otherwise show .next_song? Or did you want this per `my_playlist`? If so, then you could just create a separate template for the body of `my_playlist`.

Comment: I apologize for my comment, I didn't think your solution proposal or my question through. I have still not solved my problem, but I think your solution answers the question posed crrectly.